# Android make ?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless go farther?

Tags: android, xml

Android has the attribute android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" which makes a ripple go slightly past the view bounds.

For whatever reason, I can not create a ripple that does the same thing, so is there any way to make the above atrribute extend farther than it does now?